# iPhone:How to manage UITextfield delegate methods on dynamic number of customcells

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have dynamic number of textfields in my tableview, I put each textfield into a customcell in IB  and load the cells by nibName.

I want to validate and show alert as user enters data, also when editingisDone I want to get the input value from user and save it to the relavent object.

for instance these are some delegate methods I can use:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   //save the data
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    //hide the keypad when done is pressed
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange{}
```

2 questions:

1-When getting user input and validating the input how will I know which textfield's delegate is fired since there are dynamic numbers of cells and textfields, and how can I manage this?

2-For hiding the keyboard I did this but not sure this is correct;
     -In IB I opened the customcell-->right click uitextfield and connect its didEndonExit to **FirstResponder**'s textFieldDoneEditing method. This works but I can't return if I didnt add any chars to textfield. so it forces to write something in order to press the button.

Comment: Use the tag property to figure out which UITextField fired the delegate. You could use the row indexPath for example as a tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*With regards to your first question ...*

In the following code I'll assume you have one `UITextField` in each cell. I'll also assume you've created an `UITableViewCell` subclass called `CustomCell` which contains an `UITextField`.

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (!cell)
   {
      cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault identifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
      cell.textField.delegate = self;
   }
   return cell; 
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate 

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   NSLog(@"textField tag: %d", textField.tag); // this will show which textField did end editing ...
}
```

Comment: tnx this worked great, do you have ideas about rest of the question? cant return before enter something

Comment: I'll try to post a solution for your second question later today.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your second question; if I understand your problem correctly, unchecking "Auto-enable Return Key" in the textfield's properties in IB should allow you to press the return button even when it's empty. I tested this on a simple textfield in a UIView, but it should work in your case.

[image]